# jquery if image has attribute on click

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I am just learning how to use jquery correctly and I cannot seem to figure out why this approach doesn't stop the anchor from redirecting.

Basically, I want to check if an image has a certain data tag in its anchor and when clicked it stops the link and does something (basically making my own light box).

html

```
<ul class="imageList imgListIntro">
    <li>
        <a href="img/cc/intro-1.jpg"  
           data-ocular="test-1" 
           data-title="Test" 
           class="hvr-wobble-vertical">
            <img src="img/cc/intro-1.jpg" class="" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

js

```
if ($('img a').attr('data-ocular')){
    $('img a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Ocular Tag');
    });              
}
```

Comment: $('a[data-ocular]') should work - it means select all the a tags that have a data-ocular attribute.

Comment: I think it should be noted that [`<img />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) elements should *never* contain other elements (it's an empty element, and self closing), so the selector `img a` doesn't make sense from the get go. Most of the answers seem to have missed this.

Comment: We didn't miss it. It's just not part of the question, and his markup doesn't actually include anything inside the image tag. Only his selector is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues with your code. First, using the if statement to check for the selector's existence isn't required. That is because jQuery will fail silently and as a result if the selector is not matched then nothing happens. So just directly assign the event handler.

Mainly, the selector used was incorrect as it was slightly backwards and did not take into account the data- attribute. In selection, the parent -> child references go from left to right. So the left is the parent and the right most are the children in order. In this case we want to have an anchor element with a data attribute which contains an image. That would look like this `$('a[data-ocular] img')`

```js
$('a[data-ocular] img').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('Ocular Tag');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="imageList imgListIntro">
  <li>
    <a href="img/cc/intro-1.jpg"  data-ocular="test-1" data-title="Test" class="hvr-wobble-vertical"><img src="img/cc/intro-1.jpg" class=""></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. It makes complete sense now. Side question: can I add [attribute name] after any element to check if it exists? like $('img[data-title]')

Comment: @Packy - Yes you can, that would also work. You can also see the whole list of selectors available here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @Packy - The selectors used by jQuery are basically css selectors. It essentially wraps the [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) (there is also querySelectorAll) feature of native javascript. See more on selectors in general here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors and here: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#grammar

Comment: Thanks. This makes so much more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

The `a` tag is not a child of the `img` tag. It's reversed. But you can reduce that to:

```
$('a[data-ocular]').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('Ocular Tag');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just bind based on a CSS selector. In this case, bind all "a" tags with the attribute data-ocular.

```
      $('a[data-ocular]').click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          alert('Ocular Tag');
          return false;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the attribute selector: `$('a[data-ocular]')`.

```
$('a[data-ocular]').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).attr('data-ocular'));
});
```

In English this says: "Select all anchor tags with the attribute 'data-ocular' and add this click handler to them." The click handler prevents the default click behavior of the anchor and then it shows an alert with the value of the `data-ocular` attribute on the link that was clicked. `this` refers to the element that was clicked and wrapping it with `$(this)` gives you the JQuery sugar that allows you to call `.attr` and get the attribute value.

Demo: http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/qdrqYm